# why is my ANN performing worse with more training data?

Tags: python, neural-network, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a NN to approximate the results of a non-linear finite element model. I'm using `sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor` with the LBFGS solver and relu activation function. One layer should be enough for what I read in reference articles.

At first, I had only 500 cases in my database and the NN performed fine (not too good, but better than expected). Now that I have 3000 cases, the NN won't reach the same performance no matter what I try.

Can anyone please shed some light on what might be happening?

Comment: There can be many possible causes, e.g. problems in the data, bad hyperparameter values, implementation errors. It is difficult to tell the reason with the info you provided.

Comment: if performance is low on test set, then maybe overfitting is a problem with more data/more training

Comment: @noe, I'm still running the GridSearch and seeing that the error measures are not achieving the same quality as before

Comment: @NikosM., thanks so much for your feedback. I'll plot the error measures for different training data sizes to see what is going on.